# How to prevent XSS with ZF2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, xss

Need to escape this line before rendering it in HTML:

```
$this->view->zipcode = $this->getRequest()->getParam('zipcode','');
```

I didn't work with ZF2  before, I want to properly `escape` this line to protect my site against XSS.

I don't know how to use correctly `escape()`, `htmlspecialchars()`, and others in Zend Framework 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are tons of questions on how to use escape HTML, and using `htmlspecialchars()` isn't exactly rocket science, but since you are scoping this to ZF2, let's try to make this useful.

ZF2 includes the [Escaper](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.escaper.introduction.html) class exactly for this situation.

It's easy enough to use it:

```
$escaper             = new Zend\Escaper\Escaper('utf-8');
$unsafe_input        = $this->getRequest()->getParam('zipcode','');
$safe_output         = $escaper->escapeHtml($unsafe_input);
$this->view->zipcode = $safe_output;
```

The class has also specific methods to deal with JS, CSS, URLs, and HTML attributes. Also, be aware than the parameter you pass to the `Escaper` constructor should match the character encoding of the page you are rendering. UTF-8 is mostly a safe bet nowadays, but other encoding like 'ISO-8859-1'  are not uncommon.

As some people have said in comments, you can also do the escaping directly on the view using the built-in helper. The view should either be aware of what data might come from user input, or you just escape every variable you are going to output:

So in your view, following your example, you'd do:

```
 $this->escapeHtml($this->zipcode);
```